# Java com.sun.jna callback function from a c++ application

Tags: java, callback, jna

I have a DLL written in C++ that I can not change. It has the following exposed function

```
// c++ 
DllExport unsigned int ProcessMessage( char * in_message, USHORT in_message_length, char * connectionString, bool ( SendMessage)( char * connectionString, BYTE * payload, USHORT iPayloadSize )  );
```

I have a Java application that needs to call this DLL function. I am currently using a java library [com.sun.jna](https://github.com/twall/jna)

```
// Java 
public class main {
    public interface CBlargAPI extends Library {
        interface sendMessage_t extends Callback {
            boolean invoke(String connectionString, Pointer payload, short iPayloadSize );
        }
        int ProcessMessage( byte[] in_message, short in_message_length, String connectionString, sendMessage_t SendMessage ) ; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // Override function thingy (#A) 
        CBlarg.sendMessage_t sendMessage_fn  = new CBlarg.sendMessage_t() {
            @Override
            public boolean invoke(String connectionString, Pointer payload, short iPayloadSize) {
                System.out.println("sendMessage_t: " )  ;
                return false; 
                }
            };         
        }
        CBlargAPI.INSTANCE.ProcessMessage( receivePacket.getData(), (short) receivePacket.getLength(), connectionString, sendMessage_fn ); 
    }

    // static member function (#B) 
    public static boolean SendUDPMessage( String connectionString, Pointer payload, short length )  {    
        // ToDo: I want to use this one. 
    }
}
```

Currently this is working with the `override function thingy (#A)` but I want to use the `static member function (#B)` instead. I have tried a few things without success such as

```
// Errors with "cannot find symbol, symbol: class SendUDPMessage, location: class main" 
CBACnetAPI.sendMessage_t sendMessage_fn  = new main.SendUDPMessage();
```

I am primary a c++ programmer and rarely touch java

**My question is:**

- How do I call the static member function `SendUDPMessage()` as the callback instead of the `Override function thingy (#A)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `override function thingy (#A)` call the `static member function(#B)`.  Java does not have function pointers, so you need an interface object to serve that purpose.

Why do you need to do #B over #A?

Comment: I just wanted the class to be set up cleaner.